# WCF Service Falling Through if Statement in catch(Exception ex)

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have a WCF Service, in one of my methods I am attempting to throw an explicit FaultException. This throw is being caught by my catch statement, my intention was to check if the exception is of my explicit type and if so rethrow. The debugger shows this is happening successfully but also throws the new FaultException found after the else. It is the generic FaultException that gets sent to my client. I cannot explain this behavior?

```
try
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        var obj = GetSomeObject(objectId, db);

        if (!obj.Conditional)
            throw new FaultException<ValidateStatusFault>(new ValidateStatusFault { Details = "Object '" + obj.Id + "' has not been some condition.", Issue = "Object '" + obj.Id + "' cannot be validated." });

        // Additional checks.
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is FaultException<ValidateStatusFault>)
        throw; // I reach this breakpoint successfully.
    else
        throw new FaultException(ex.Message); // I also reach this breakpoint?
}
```

Comment: Why are you throwing a FaultException in the using? FaultException's are normally used to indicate some kind of connection issue, or something similar.

Comment: When not using the debugger does the code function as it should?

Comment: @Servy At first I thought it did not, but it appears that you may have hit it on the head. It seems the debugger hits both breakpoints but I am receiving the explicit FaultException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, 'if statements' in catch block is not working. You have to use like below.

Every single throw statements will be thrown regardless of any if statements.

```
try {
    tryStatements
}
catch(FaultException<ValidateStatusFault> faultException){ 
    catchStatements
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw new FaultException(ex.Message); 
}
finally {
    finallyStatements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this check explicitly. you can have 2 different exceptions catch and the filtering will be done for you.

```
try
{
}
catch (FaultException<ValidateStatusFault> faultException)
{
        throw; // I reach this breakpoint successfully.

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw new FaultException(ex.Message); 
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP's problem is that they don't understand how exception handling works in .net.